# jquery.mobile swipe page navigation restrict to div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working with this jquery.mobile example to use swipe to navigate pages.

[jquery.mobile swipe-page example](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-page/)

Now I don´t want to have the swipe on the whole page. I want to bind it only to an div element.

I have a div element on my page

```
<div id="divSWIPE"></div>
```

I have looked at the source code of the example and I think I found the part that handles the swipe event.

```
// The same for the navigating to the previous page
$( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
    var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );

    if ( prev && ( event.target === $( this )[ 0 ] ) ) {
        navprev( prev );
    }
});
```

I have tried to modify this but I can´t get this working only on the div element.
I have tried this

```
$( "#divSWIPE" ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
```

and this

```
$( document ).on( "swiperight", "divSWIPE", function( event ) {
```

But this doesn´t work.

How can I bind this to my div element?

Comment: Add sample html markup to understand what you want to perform when swipe is triggered. You want to navigate to next/prev page in DOM or retrieve data from swiped div/page?

Answer (score 1):

Attack swipe listeners on `pagecreate`. The below code will check if there is a page in DOM before the current page. Or retrieve value from custom attribute in page div `data-prev`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {
  var page = e.target;

  $("#divSwipe", page).on("swiperight", function () {

    var prev = $(this).closest(".ui-page").prev("[data-role=page]");

    /* or read custom attribute */

    var prev = $(this).closest(".ui-page").data("prev");

    if ( prev.length > 0 || typeof prev != "undefined" ) {

      /* navigate or do something else */
      $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", prev);

    }

  });
});
```